# Number of trials needed to increment a counter variable

Tags: probability, polynomial

Truthfully I'm not even sure what the proper name for this sort of trial is, so I'll just describe the whole setup.

Suppose I have an integer variable **n**, which starts at zero and gets incremented every time there is a "success".

Then suppose what I guess you could call the "difficulty" of a successful trial is defined by some polynomial function that I've written **p(n)** such that as **n** increases, the probability of success gets increasingly smaller.  That is to say **p(n=1) >> p(n=1500)**.

Now suppose I roll a random 100-sided die, and compare the value I rolled **d** with the value returned by **p**.  If **p(n) <= d** then I call it a success, and I increment **n** by 1.  Otherwise, I don't increment n, and I roll again.

How would I go about calculating the number of dice rolls required before n reaches some arbitary value (say, 1500?)?

Comment: Probabilities are constrained to [0,1], yet polynomial functions always eventually go off to either $\infty$ or $-\infty$. Given you said $n$ is arbitrary, how will your probability function $p(n)$ respect the constraints on probabilities?

Comment: When you say 'calculate the number of trials', it's a random variable. Are you after the distribution of the number of trials or some summary of the distribution, like the mean?

Comment: One approach would be to consider casting the problem as a Markov chain, where the state is the number of successes and the transition matrix is bidiagonal. Alternatively, one could use numerical convolution on the geometric distributions (number of trials) that come with each increment for any fixed number of successes (one might actually use pgfs and do some algebra I suppose, but with potentially large *n* that could be onerous). One could also look at methods for the Poisson-binomial. However, to actually 'solve' the problem of finding the distribution, I'd probably use simulation, myself.

Comment: @Glen_b:  There are a myriad of ways to construct a function whose range lies within [0,1] (cosine and the error function come readily to mind, and there exist polynomial approximations for both) and besides that's not really the question.  Let's just suffice it to say that the function exists and it works.

Comment: @Glen_b : as far as "the distribution of the number of trials" I'm not sure I fully understand what that means.  I don't _think_ I need a function describing the frequencies of different dice rolls.  I just want to know how many trials I should expect to have to run before n reaches some arbitrary value.  But for the sake of argument, let's say I want the mean of the distribution:  how would I calculate it?

Comment: "how many trials I should expect" would normally be interpreted to be "the mean of the distribution of the number of trials" so you're being nice and consistent. The mean should be relatively easy.